# SSHd listen on OpenVPN's IP ?

Tags: debian, openvpn, ssh

I've got a server with SSH and OpenVPN services. I'd like to make sshd listen only on the openvpn ip. The problem is, until openVPN is up and tun0 is set, sshd can't be bind to the openvpn's ip.

I'm running debian stable on my box.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the start of sshd from various RCX (update-rc.d).
Then you could add a line into the openvpn startup script that starts sshd when openvn is up.
You could make a bit better checking if the ip of the openvpn is up and runnning and then startup the sshd.

Comment: Okay thanks for this answer, but I was looking for a cleaner solution, or at least something better integrated to debian.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server and read [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-run-firewall-script-as-soon-as-eth0-interface-brings-up.html).

Answer (score 0):

Write a "post-up" OpenVPN script that restarts the `sshd`.